# Updating Multiple Rows and Columns of database in Joomla

Tags: mysql, database, joomla, insert-update

I have a database similar to this:

table name = jos_school ... id = Primary key,  name = Unique key

```
id    name        no_of_students    no_of_staffs    fees
1     schoolA     0                 0               0
2     schoolB     0                 0               0
...
...
```

In phpMyAdmin I did something like this, and it worked (successfully updated multiple rows and columns),

```
UPDATE jos_school
    SET no_of_students    = CASE name
            WHEN 'schoolA' THEN '1523'
            WHEN 'schoolB' THEN '546'
            ....
        END,
        no_of_staffs    = CASE name
            WHEN 'schoolA' THEN '1234'
            WHEN 'schoolB' THEN '346'
            ....
        END
WHERE name IN ('schoolA', 'schoolB')
```

However, I was not able to update the table USING JOOMLA's Update methods. I don't want to use foreach and update the table over 1000 times. I want to execute a single query.

I've also read: http://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase#Updating_a_Record
and dint found it helpful in this case. 
So, can someone point me to the right direction.

Comment: If you provide the code you used to try and update the database, that would help.

Comment: @Lodder I tried various variations, none of them worked so i came up with the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can query as below,

```
  // Create a new query object.
            $db     =  &JFactory::getDBO();
            $query  = $db->getQuery(true);

            // Select the required fields from the table.
            $query="UPDATE jos_school SET no_of_students    = CASE name";
               foreach($data as $d)
               {                
                   $query.=".....";
               }
              $query.=".....";
            $db->setQuery((string)$query);
```

Hope that helps ...

Comment: This query uses old coding standards. Please try to keep people up to date with newer coding standards. Nor have you defined the database table prefix (replace **jos_**)

Comment: Thank you, your way does the trick.

However, I wanted to know if there is any way of achieving it using joomla functions.